# Altering keyboard layout mapping in Gnome in Ubuntu 9

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, keyboard-layout

How to change keyboard layout mapping in gnome?

I'd like to assign `Ctrl` functionality to `Ins`. It is impossible to do that in Ubuntu Keyboard Manager. Are there applications fro changing keyboard mapping for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

[xmodmap](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0/xmodmap.1.html) will let you re-map keys. Look through the docs to find out the appropriate key codes to use. Hope that works for you :)